# Fancybox iFrame modal : How can I avoid its resizing when I reduce the size of the browser window?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox, modal-dialog

I have created a modal based on an iframe, using Fancybox. It's for a login box. But whenever I reduce the size of the browser window, the fancybox reduces itself as well and I cannot control it. I have set the size of width and height of this fancybox, but it keeps resizing when I Reduce the size of the browser window. How can I stop that behavior ?
Thanks.

Comment: OK My solution was using numbers instead of strings in the width and height declaration.Instead of using :  'width': '400',  use 'width': 400 ... that was all folks. simple.

Answer (score 1):

Set `autoscale` & `autoDimensions` to `false`

http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: AutoDimensions work for ajax modals, not for iframes. I set the autoscale to false, but it still does it. Probably is something else.

Comment: $("#various3").fancybox({
            'width': '40%',
            'height': '23%',
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });